# Send and receive data with XML

Tags: java, xml, url

I have 2 programs : `Agent.java` & `Simulator.java` (don't worry about names, you can call them A & B respectively). Now, I want to send `job` object from `Agent` to `Simulator` using XML format. The `job` class looks like:

```
public class job {
    int JobID;
    job(int JobID){
        this.JobID=JobID;
    }

    public int getJobID(){
        //get JobID variable value from here
    }

    public void setJobID(int temp_JobID){
        //change variable JobID here
    }

}
```

Now I store it in a XML format and send to Simulator. I know that I can use other ways to send object `job` but this XML file format is standard to be followed in my project.
On the other hand , I receive `job` object, get data from it and use them in program.

**So my Q. is:** How do I send data using XML? I saw many Q. related to this but they refer to an XML file on hard drive, convert to String, send it and then receive in other program. I think this is not going to work in my case because I have many jobs are coming continuously, and I will receive them on real-time. So, its bad idea to store them on my compute. Isn't there any XML file sender and receiver?

Comment: What problems are arising by just using XML and what exactly do you mean by jobs are coming continuously and will receive in real time.

Comment: Agent.java is creating job object in real time (say every 1 second) and sending it to Simulator.java.

Comment: How do you send job data to Simulator. If you are invoiking that Simulator API or any means then you can have the converted Job XML(by marshalling) as String and pass it to Simulator where you Unmarshall to Job object again. Use Jibx for that!

Comment: @Pokuri So, Do I create separate XML file for every job?

Comment: did you look at jdom?

Comment: @Nikhil No need of any XML file. You will have your Job object in  XML string format. Then pass that string to other end... If your are using any JMS service make it part of Message object

Comment: @Pokuri I HAVE TO use XML. It is a standard in industry to use that format so that any other program (written in Java/C/R/.....) can read jobs.

Comment: @Pokuri sorry for 'dynamic' word. It has been removed. You suggesting me to store XML file for evry job  on hard drive. Won't that consume lots of disk space when I run program for 5-6 hours? By 'anyone should be able to read ' , I mean that at the same time simulator.java reads it, other program should be able to read. Its not that other program will read later.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look at [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html). You can create xsd-files from your specified format, generate annotated job class from it and also use the generated object factories. Then you have your jobs in memory and you can create a queue of them.

Comment: JAXB looks to be specifically for Java. If I want to send XML file to other program (written in any other language which understands XML) will I be able to achieve it?

Comment: Sure, and probably you can benefit from the created xsd-schemas.

Comment: With JAXB you can also start from your own Java objects (no XML schemas required).

Answer (score 0):

In one of the projects, I used JDOM for exchanging data between files in xml.
Class A constructs xml document from the object's fields and send that document to class B. Class B can create object from that received document.

Comment: Yes, but can any other program (written in other language) access that?

Comment: Well, you are using agent.java and simulator.java and JDOM is Java/XML integration. If you care for other languages, you must specify that.

Comment: I thought, if I'll send XML to that program only but will JDOM be able to send XML to program in other language which understands XML?

Answer (score 0):

No need of any file for posting jobs. You can use in-memory objects.

Try using [JIBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/) to Marshall/Unmarshall you job object and have it in memory instead of in file. Once you have that Job object marshall to XML in string format send it to Simulator. On the Simulator side unmashall the XML to Job object again.

If you are using any JMS service for posting jobs to Simulator make that XML string part of you Message.

Comment: I HAVE TO use XML. It is a standard in industry to use that format so that any other program (written in Java/C/R/.....) can read jobs.

Comment: Then what do you mean by dynamic XML sender and receiver when anyone should be able to read that? If possible log that job XML to console or store into DB to read them later. If you have any UI then you can show that job information from XML on screen

Comment: sorry for 'dynamic' word. It has been removed. You suggesting me to store XML file for evry job on hard drive. Won't that consume lots of disk space when I run program for 5-6 hours? By 'anyone should be able to read ' , I mean that at the same time simulator.java reads it, other program should be able to read. Its not that other program will read later.

Comment: mmm! that could be an issue. When all programs pointing to same folder for jobs then we cannot delete the file once it picked up by a program. Then we have to identify a mechanism to delete job details either based on each job completion time or cleaning the folder with a time interval(i.e for every 15 min.). Or any better approach...